# VB+Crystal report

Tags: ms-access, vba, crystal-reports

I wrote this code but I got "Run time error '91':"

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    openConnection

    If Me.cmbMonth = "" And Me.cmbYear = "" Then
      MsgBox "Please select MONTH and YEAR"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    With crystalrpt

        .ReportFileName = App.Path & "\Report\VariableReport.rpt" <-- ERROR IS HERE
        .SelectionFormula = "{SW.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {SW.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {SFW.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {SFW.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {OT.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {OT.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {CL.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {CL.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {RM.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {RM.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {EL.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {EL.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {TRANS.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {TRANS.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {WD.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {WD.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {MP.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {MP.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {NONSTOCK.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {NONSTOCK.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & "" & _
        " and {PACK.dtaMonth}='" & cmbMonth.Text & "' and {PACK.dtaYear}=" & dtaYear.Text & ""
        .WindowTitle = "Report"
        .Action = 1 'Will Show The Report

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot see where you have set crystalreport to an object.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are trying to create an instance of a class (an object) from a class that is present on the machines you tested it on, but not on the machine it's been deployed to..... for example, I happen to know that I can make a VB program utilize a class for Nero Burning Rom.... I can make a nero object, and use it's methods and properties...... but that will only work on machines that have the Nero libraries installed. If it's not installed, when you try to make the object (either through early or late bindings with new or createobject), the variable that SHOULD refer to the object is still set to Nothing, because the library failed to create an instance of the requested class.....